# Python Selenium Loop thru select menu

Tags: python, selenium

I need to loop thru the select menu on this page:

https://printcopy.info/?mod=erc&brand=Kyocera&model=TASKalfa+307ci&page=1

The select menu has a display: none so i did the following to get the values:

```
    element = driver.find_element_by_id('selectNumPages')   
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].removeAttribute('style');", element)
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('selectNumPages'))
    for opt in select.options:
        print(opt.text)
```

This outputs each value in the select menu, now i need to click on each one so that i **scrape** data on each page.

I tried:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_id("selectNumPages-button")
button.click()
```

This clicks the select menu but the page url doesn't change

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***UPDATE***

I ended up using ActionChains

Answer (score 0):

This is custom drop down . you can refer below code:

```
driver.get('https://printcopy.info/?mod=erc&brand=Kyocera&model=TASKalfa+307ci&page=1')
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

selector = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='selectNumPages-button']//span[@class='ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s']")))
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(selector).click().perform()
names=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='selectNumPages-menu']//li")))
for name in names:
    print(name.text)
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
```

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer and hit upvote button from your end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through the pages, you do not need to click on each page. You could ust take the url of each page

https://printcopy.info/?mod=erc&brand=Kyocera&model=TASKalfa+307ci&page=1

As you can see there is "page=1". You could use that in order to loop through the pages. There are 23 pages so..

```
page_num = 23

for i in range(1,23):
    pg = str(i)
    driver.get('https://printcopy.info/?mod=erc&brand=Kyocera&model=TASKalfa+307ci&page='.pg)
```

Then just select the items you need.

P.S. i am new to this as well, so please correct me if i am wrong.